# how to stop spark execution programmatically when encounter bad data

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, rdd

I want to add data validity check in the RDD transformation. What is the most elegant way to stop processing on invalid data? It runs in yarn cluster

Answer (score 0):

Use a Filter transformation and check for the condition.It would not return the bad records. Now compare the count of this RDD with the previous RDD. When it is lesser, trigger an condition.

Comment: i want to stop fast. not waiting for all data processed.